# Deleting duplicate rows based on the latest date

Tags: excel, vba

I have a need to delete duplicate rows. I delete them using the code written below. Everything is perfectly deleted, but how can I make the code leave a string with the latest date? For example, I have duplicate rows with dates: 27-jul-20 and 30-jul-20. I need it to delete all duplicate lines except the line with the oldest date. The code takes into account not only the date, but also duplicate names.

```
Dim a As Long
For a = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:A" & a), Cells(a, 1)) > 1 Then Rows(a).Delete
Next
```

Comment: Just filter your data from recent to oldest on that specific column first. Then delete all duplicates over remaining columns. There is a build-in function to do so. You can obviously call it through VBA too. That would avoid running through all lines and calling worksheetfunctions.

Comment: **There is nothing in your question or the code to indicate in which column the date resides**

Comment: To be honest, I'm new to vba, and the code was "stolen" almost unchanged.. The only thing it does is delete all duplicates in the entire table. If you can add code to filter by date (I have a column with a date-this is M), tell me how to do it, please.